# Esiste un nome per gli aggettivi che cambiano significato a seconda della posizione?

Tags: adjectives

Esempio:

> La Cina è un grande paese.

significa che è un paese importante, eccezionale, straordinario...

> La Cina è un paese grande.

significa che è geograficamente molto esteso.

Come sono chiamati gli aggettivi che, come *grande* nell'esempio, cambiano significato a seconda che siano posizionati prima o dopo il sostantivo?

Comment: Temo che il nome sia “aggettivo”. `;-)` Per quasi tutti la posizione dà una sfumatura di significato diversa.

Comment: @egreg Ahahahah

Comment: Questo estratto dall’Accademia della Crusca può essere utile: ***Sulla posizione
dell'aggettivo qualificativo in italiano***. http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/posizione-dellaggettivo-qualificativo-italia

Comment: @Gio Grazie per il link, molto interessante, centra in pieno la questione.

Comment: Vedi anche questo [link](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2014/11/20/la-posizione-dellaggettivo-qualificativo/)

Comment: @alexjo Molto interessante, grazie e buon Natale!